# natbib creates no errors but no output either

Tags: natbib

I am using `natbib` as my bibliography style, the strange thing is that when I run my code, I get no errors or warnings what so ever, But I get 0 pages of output! 
Its really strange, I am sure that the code is right, when I switch back to plain style, I get my output perfectly. 
I am totally new to LaTaX appreciate if you can help me with that. (I am using TeXnicCenter.)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: `natbib` isn't a bibliography style, it's a package. Can you provide an example (a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that))? That is, create a document with just the necessary stuff -- `documentclass`, `natbib` package, `bibliographystyle`, `document` environment. Edit you question to include it.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you have a `\bibliographystyle{<somestyle>}` instruction somewhere in your document.

I can't help but sense a bit of confusion in your expression "I am using `natbib` as my bibliography style". The `natbib` package first and foremost provides various citation commands (e.g., `\citet` and `\citep`) that greatly augment the functionality of the "basic LaTeX" `\cite` command. For instance, the "basic LaTeX" `\cite` command isn't all that well suited for creating authoryear-style citations; in contrast the `\citet` and `\citep` commands (when used in conjunction with a suitable bibliography style file -- and lots of them are suitable...) can handle this chore with ease.

*In addition*, and maybe a bit confusingly at first, the `natbib` package also provides several bibliography style files -- such as `plainnat.bst`, `unsrtnat.bst`, and `abbrvnat.bst` -- that augment and improve on the functionality of the "basic BibTeX" style files `plain.bst`, `unsrt.bst`, and `abbrv.bst`. However, it's important to keep in mind that if one uses the `natbib` package for its citation commands, one is *not* forced into using one of the package's bibliography style files as well.

Summing up, it's up to the user to specify the bibliography style that best suits his/her bibliography (and citation) formatting needs.

Comment: Thank you very much guys. I am amazed by the level of your helpfulness. I just realized that I have to install the package first and then start using it, Yes I know, I am such a noobie!